# How to use Fortran compilers to parse-check or pretty print source files?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, syntax, standards, fortran

Is there a way to tell ifort or gfortran to just try to parse a source file (no include following, no compilation, no linking, etc) to tell us whether they find the syntax of the file acceptable / valid for a given Fortran version (77, 90, 95, ...) or at least valid at all?

I'm working on a piece of software that will parse and analyze Fortran source files, perform transformations on their semantic representation and generate new Fortran source code files as result.

Until my (standards-adherent) strict parser is ready to roll, I first plan to use a relaxed one. That relaxed parser

- must parse all files ifort and gfortran parse
- may also parse files ifort and gfortran rejects (that's why I called it names like relaxed, forgiving, etc. hehe ^__^")

. That's why I would love to know whether, at the initial stages of this project, we could use delegate the work of strict syntactic validation to common compilers.

Comment: So your software will be able to take our old FORTRAN 77 code and make it into nice, free-spaced Fortran 90?

Comment: No, my aim is to build a Fortran front-end for an automatic differentiation engine. [my blog](http://sert.homedns.org/cetin/blog/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try looking into the man page?

gfortran should support

```
-fsyntax-only //Check the code for syntax errors, but don't do anything beyond that.
```

ifortran should support

```
-fsyntax-only / -syntax-only / -y //all meaning the same
// Specifies that the source file should be checked only for correct syntax.
// No code is generated, no object file is produced, and some error checking done
// by the optimizer is bypassed. This option lets you do a quick syntax check of
//your source file.
```

For ifortran also look into these options

```
-e90
-e95
-stand f90
-stand f95
-noinclude
```